# Automatically refreshing Materialized view at Irregular time intervals

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I need to automatically refresh a Materialized view at irregular intervals, like 0800hrs, 1200hrs 1800hrs and 2200hrs. I am only able to get as far as scheduling the refresh at regular intervals, like given below

...

```
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT sysdate+(6/24)
AS Select * from Employee;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `CASE` statement in your `NEXT`.  So you can do something like

```
NEXT (CASE WHEN to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'HH24' )) >= 22 
           THEN trunc(sysdate+1) + interval '8' hour
           ...
           ELSE null
       END)
```

For general sanity, I would generally create a new function (i.e. `get_next_refresh_time`) that implements this `CASE` statement and just reference the function in your materialized view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_refresh_time 
  RETURN DATE
IS
  l_dt DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'HH24' )) >= 22 
              THEN trunc(sysdate+1) + interval '8' hour
              WHEN to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'HH24' )) <  8
              THEN trunc(sysdate) + interval '8' hour
              WHEN to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'HH24' )) between 8 and 11
              THEN trunc(sysdate) + interval '12' hour
              WHEN to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'HH24' )) between 12 and 17
              THEN trunc(sysdate) + interval '18' hour
              WHEN to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'HH24' )) between 18 and 21
              THEN trunc(sysdate) + interval '22' hour
              ELSE null
          END
    INTO l_dt
    FROM dual;
  RETURN l_dt;
END;

NEXT get_next_refresh_time;
```

Comment: But actually when i tried to use this command i am getting an error saying 
'Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-12899: value too large for column "SYS"."SNAP$"."AUTO_FUN" (actual: 748, maximum: 200)
12899. 00000 -  "value too large for column %s (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"'

I didnt get this error when i tried to use just sysdate +8/24...

Comment: @user1532517 - Then you'll need to use the function approach that I suggested.  I wasn't sure off the top of my head what the maximum length of the acceptable `CASE` statement is.

Comment: @Justin Cave Hi I have the same pro with the first method, and then I created a function as you suggested in second method, and use NEXT get_next_refresh_time in my definition of Materialized view, but I always got error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here. Do you have any ideas about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @deli - It sounds like you want to post a new question that includes a full, reproducible test case.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use DBMS_SCHEDULER and set up a job to call DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_mview.htm#ARPLS027).  This has the added benefit of more options for your refresh as well.